# Can I change the Associated values of a enum?

Tags: swift, enums

I am reading the Swift tour document, and facing a problem.
Here is the code:

```
enum SimpleEnum {
    case big(String)
    case small(String)
    case same(String)

    func adjust() {
        switch self {
        case let .big(name):
            name +=  "not"
        case let .small(name):
            name +=  "not"
        case let .same(name):
            name +=  "not"
        }
    }
}
```

The function `adjust()` won't work, I wonder if there is a way to change the  Associated value of an enum, and how?

Comment: It's worth noting that an enum that has the same associated values for each case is *much* better modelled as a struct – e.g `struct S { enum Kind { case big, small, same }; var kind: Kind; var name: String }`. This greatly simplifies such mutations.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Your most immediate problem is that you're attempting to change the value of an immutable variable (declared with `let`) when you should be declaring it with `var`. This won't solve this particular problem though since your `name` variable contains a copy of the associated value, but in general this is something that you need to be aware of.

If you want to solve this, you need to declare the `adjust()` function as a mutating function and reassign self on a case by case basis to be a new enum value with an associated value composed from the old one and the new one. For example:

```
enum SimpleEnum{
    case big(String)
    case small(String)
    case same(String)

    mutating func adjust() {
        switch self{
        case let .big(name):
            self = .big(name + "not")
        case let .small(name):
            self = .small(name + "not")
        case let .same(name):
            self = .same(name + "not")
        }
    }
}

var test = SimpleEnum.big("initial")
test.adjust()

switch test {
case let .big(name):
    print(name) // prints "initialnot"
case let .small(name):
    print(name)
case let .same(name):
    print(name)
}
```