# Changing associated value of enum Swift

Tags: swift, enums

How do I change a specific associated value of an enum

```
enum Origin {
    case search(searchTerm: String, filtered: Bool)
    case category(categoryName:String, subcategoryName:String)

}

@objc class GameSession: NSObject
{
    var gameOrigin: Origin?

    ...

    @objc func setIsSearchFiltered(filtered:Bool)
    {
        if (<gameOrigin is of type .search?>)
        {
            self.gameOrigin = <change "filtered" associated value to new value>
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

[This question with answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488603/can-i-change-the-associated-values-of-a-enum), unfortunately, lately didn't help me.

Comment: @Luda can you show the actual code for assigning/updating the `gameOrigin`?

Comment: @Kamran, this is what I am looking for

Comment: @MartinR Can you please write down how would you do it? The new enum value should have the same associated values except of "filtered"

Comment: @MartinR C What worked was case .search(let searchTerm, _):
 gameOrigin = .search(searchTerm: searchTerm, filtered: filtered). You can put this as an answer. By the way, is there a way to use if instead of case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only assign a new enumeration value to the variable.
As in [Can I change the Associated values of a enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488603/can-i-change-the-associated-values-of-a-enum/31488680#31488680),
the associated values of the current values can be retrieved in a switch statement,
with a case pattern which binds the associated value to a local variable.

The currently associated `filtered` value is not needed, therefore
we can use a wildcard pattern `_` at that position.

Since `var gameOrigin: Origin?` is an optional, we need an “optional pattern” with a trailing question mark.

```
switch gameOrigin {
case .search(let searchTerm, _)?:
    gameOrigin = .search(searchTerm: searchTerm, filtered: filtered)
default:
    break
}
```

The same can be done also in an if-statement with `case` and pattern
matching:

```
if case .search(let searchTerm, _)? = gameOrigin {
    gameOrigin = .search(searchTerm: searchTerm, filtered: filtered)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift change Enum associated value**

[[Swift Enum]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57109262/4770877)

One more example with `mutating`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219124/4770877) function

```
enum Section {
    case info(header: String)
    
    mutating func change(newHeader: String) {
        switch self {
        case .info(let header):
            self = .info(header: "\(header) \(newHeader)")
        }
    }
}

//changing
var mySection = Section.info(header: "Hello world")
mySection.change(newHeader: "And Peace")

//printing
switch mySection {
case .info(let header):
    print(header) //"Hello world And Peace"
}
```