# Change Value of associated enum

Tags: swift, struct, enums

I have this `associated enum:`

```
public typealias TextFieldInfo = (type: TextFieldType, title: String, entry: String)

public enum TextFieldType {
    case text
    case number
    case capitalLetter
    case date
    case entry
}

public enum TextFieldModelEnum {
    case generic(type: TextFieldType, title: String)
    case entry(type: TextFieldType, title: String, entry: String)

    var info: TextFieldInfo {
        switch self {
        case .generic(let type, let title):
            return (type, title, "")
        case .entry(let type, let title, let entry):
            return (type, title, entry)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change the value `entry` in the method below, but it gives me an error on the first line:

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'String'

```
extension ThirdViewController: TextProtocol {
    func getText(text: String) {
        self.array[self.rowListSelected].info.entry = text
        let indexPaths = [IndexPath(row: self.rowListSelected, section: 0)]
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .none)
        print(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally figured out how to do this with a `set` for the computed property

```
var info: TextFieldInfo { 
    get {
        switch self {
        case .generic(let type, let title):
            return (type, title, "")
        case .entry(let type, let title, let entry):
            return (type, title, entry)
        }
    }
    set {
        switch self {
        case .generic:
            self = TextFieldModelEnum.generic(type: newValue.type, title: newValue.title)
        case .entry:
           self = TextFieldModelEnum.entry(type: newValue.type, title: newValue.title, entry: newValue.entry)
        }
    }
}
```

Example

```
var tf = TextFieldModelEnum.entry(type: .text, title: "A Title", entry: "An Entry")
print(tf.info.entry)
print(tf.info.title)
tf.info.entry = "new entry"
print(tf.info.entry)
tf.info.title = "new title"
print(tf.info.title)
```

Output

> An Entry
>   A Title
>   new entry
>   new title

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable `info` is a computed property, you need to use the `set` keyword to make it writeable. [This article](https://medium.com/@micosmin/swift-computed-properties-2a8fd9f88d6) explains how to do that.

Comment: And how do you do that for an enum with associated values?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is possible. In this case you need to declare a `mutating` function that changes the value. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488603/can-i-change-the-associated-values-of-a-enum for more information.

Comment: But in you answer you said the `set` keyword is needed and the link you provided uses a mutating func and not `set`. Please add a description preferable with a code example on how to solve this.