# Modifying associated values of an enum in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I have an enum of `String` type.I want to prepend a string to all cases in this particular enum.

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {

    case root = "/"
    case path1 = "/path"

}
```

The output I want is something like

```
enum MyEnum: String, CaseIterable {

    case root = "myCustomString/"
    case path1 = "myCustomString/path"

}
```

Is it possible to modify an associated value of a case of a `String` enum?

```
func modifyEnumcases(string: String) {

/// append to each cases of an enum
}

modifyEnumcases("MyCustomString")
```

I tried doing it this way [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31488603/can-i-change-the-associated-values-of-a-enum)

but this is not the use case I want to achieve.

Comment: That is not possible. `enum` cases are immutable and are evaluated at compile time. You cannot even modify the associated value of an enum case with an associated value, since each case with a different associated value is actually a different case of the enum.

Comment: Too be picky, those are not associated values, they are raw values.